# C# Iterating and Comparing/Identifying WMI Services Effectively

Tags: c#, linq, service, foreach, wmi

I am working on querying specific services on a remote server in attempt to determine the status of those services, and starting/stopping/pausing them accordingly.

A snippet of my Server object class is as follows:

```
public class Server
{
    public ManagementClass Services { get; set; }

    public List<string> TargetServices { get; set; }
}
```

I make use of the ManagementClass object to connect to my server as a sort of suite of other necessities (Scope, ConnectionOptions, and ManagementPath("Win32_Service"). TargetedServices is simply a small list of services I have defined which I intend to target within all the services returned in my connection results. An example of my TargetedService can be seen as follows:

```
    server.TargetedServices = new List<string>() { "ServiceA", "ServiceB" };
```

Now, my struggles come into play when I wish to find, from all the available services, the services I have defined in my small list.. for the purposes of isolating them and manipulating them. I have accomplished the task, but processing is running terribly slow. I am hoping to find a clever, streamline solution to this. Any thoughts?

Here is my current (*cringe*) logic:

```
    public void PingServices(List<Server> servers)
    {
        foreach(Server server in servers)
        {
            foreach(ManagementObject service in server.Services.GetInstances())
            {
                foreach(string target in server.TargetServices)
                {
                    if(service.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString() == target)
                    {
                        service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could discount the service names as you find them on each server. Then when you find them all you can immediately stop and move onto the next server? You could run on multiple threads. You need to profile though and find out what is slow.

Comment: I agree multiple threads may help the process for multiple servers. However, this process is unacceptably slow for just once server. I have looked into LINQ statements, which can merge two lists together. However, I can not merge <string> and <ManagementObject> in a way to retain .InvokeMethod()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this. I understand that instead of returning all Instances in a collection that is not comparable/filterable to strings, I'm querying what I want with a WQL (not SQL-- annoying, no in operator) statement, essentially filtering my results at the server before they are returned. Performance has increased notably.

```
string sql = string.Format("SELECT * From Win32_Service WHERE Name = {0}", string.Join(" OR Name =", server.TargetServices));

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(server.Services.Scope, new ObjectQuery()
                {
                    QueryString = sql
                });

            foreach (ManagementObject service in searcher.Get())
            {
                service.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
                //My Target Services
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first profile your routine to discover exactly what takes the longest to process. Is it the query of the servers, is it starting services, is it both?

I suspect that since you are connecting to remote servers most of the time your application is sitting around waiting for the remote servers to either respond or start their services. It would be much better if you could tell the server to do something but not wait around for it to finish.

`ManagementObject` contains a couple of overloads for `InvokeMethod` and some of them are asynchronous.  My guess is that you could improve your application by kicking off your services asynchronously which means you won't be waiting on each service to do it's thing: you just tell it to start, then move onto the next service and start it, and so on.  In this way your application is no longer waiting around for the remote server to do it's thing.

Comment: Connecting to the server is taking the longest, however, while gathering services in my original method I would simply Console.WriteLine(serviceInstance) and watch as they slowly populated my screen. Awful! Thank you for your contribution.